# Haskell Looping Construct 100% CPU

Tags: macos, haskell, ghc, osx-leopard

I have a bug I can't really figure out. System is 10.5 (32 bits) with Haskell Platform 2010, GHC 6.12

Consider the following:

```
loop :: IO ()
loop = do
    return ()
    loop

main = do
    loop
```

when compiled,

```
ghc --make test.hs
```

this code ends up taking 100% of the CPU's time. Why is that?
How do you write a program in Haskell that loops like this while being nice to the laptop's battery?

Concurrent's "yield" does not seem to do anything interesting.

Comment: FYI, the reason 'yield' doesn't do anything interesting is that 'yield' tells the Haskell runtime to yield to another Haskell thread.  Since there are no other Haskell threads, the same loop will continue without much pause.

Comment: Why on earth do you want this? Perhaps if you explain what you want to achieve (other than waste processor cycles), someone can help you with a better way to do it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Same reason a tight loop in any language eats an entire CPU.  You didn't tell it to loop any slower than "as fast as it can".  Look at `Control.Concurrent`'s `threadDelay`.

Answer (score 8):

An infinite loop with no breaks will cause 100% CPU usage in any language on any computer
If you *must* do a loop like this, use a [**delay**](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/concurrent-extra/0.5/doc/html/Control-Concurrent-Thread-Delay.html) or [**sleep**](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/unix/latest/doc/html/System-Posix-Unistd.html#v:sleep) or lower the thread's **priority** if it is eating up too many cycles.

Answer (score 4):

A similar imperative (Python-like syntax) loop would be:

```
def loop():
    x = ()
    loop()
```

Or without recursion:

```
def loop():
   while True:
       x = ()
```

All this will do in any language is tell the CPU to keep executing instructions with no useful result, forever. Without specifically telling the program to do something *other* than keep executing these instructions (such as suspend for a while between loops), how could it do anything but use 100% CPU?

`Control.Concurrent.yield` allows any other thread *in your program* to "get a turn" at execution. If there are no other threads then it doesn't do anything. If *all* your other threads are executing such a loop, then it'll still use 100% CPU. If you have other threads that are sometimes IO bound rather than CPU bound, I do not know for certain, but I'm reasonably sure Haskell's runtime system switch back to something for the CPU to do (if possible) whenever threads are waiting for IO, so you'd probably see close to 100% CPU usage if you had this loop running and `yield`ing, even if you have loads of other threads that won't use 100% CPU on their own.

If other unrelated programs are also running, then almost all modern desktop hardware and operating systems will try to share the CPU resources between them, regardless of whether you're using `yield` or not. Generally, this means that any time the other programs don't have work for the CPU your loop program will be run, *plus* it will also steal some of the CPU time that could have been used to execute other programs. This means that while this loop program is executing you would usually see close to 100% CPU usage regardless of what else is running, and using `yield` won't particularly make a difference to how much CPU time is available to other programs.

`Control.Concurrent.threadDelay` puts the thread to sleep for (at least) a given amount of time. If that leaves the CPU with nothing to execute, *then* you'll see your system running at less than 100% CPU.

Answer (score 1):

Insert a [delay](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Concurrent.html#v%3athreadDelay) into your loop, so that processor time would be given to some another process.